# Print and will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working with ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.5.

I use will_paginate to display the result of a database request.
and i well display 20 results per page and i have lets say 15 pages to display.
Now i need to print the whole list, i found out a printing method adding a link into my view file erb  <%=link_to_function("Print this Page", "javascript:print()")%>
But it only print the 20 results available on the screen. Is there a method to print the 300 results in one clic

Thanks for all advises and ideas

Answer (score 2):

The print link should send to a non paginated print page with the 300 results and then print from here, you try to print from a view which only has access to the paginated object.